# Wine log spamming syslog and filling the whole disk space in Debian 11 (WoW client)

Tags: linux, debian, wine, opengl

I am experiencing a very weird issue. My World of Warcraft client (WoTLK expansion) is spamming my /var/log/syslog, /var/log/messages and /var/log/user.log with the following:

```
Oct  9 12:37:17 debian Wow.desktop[5274]: 0074:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {bcde0395-e52f-467c-8e3d-c4579291692e} not registered
Oct  9 12:37:17 debian Wow.desktop[5274]: 0074:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {bcde0395-e52f-467c-8e3d-c4579291692e} could be created for context 0x1
Oct  9 12:37:17 debian Wow.desktop[5230]: 004e:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {bcde0395-e52f-467c-8e3d-c4579291692e} not registered
Oct  9 12:37:17 debian Wow.desktop[5230]: 004e:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {bcde0395-e52f-467c-8e3d-c4579291692e} could be created for context 0x1
Oct  9 12:37:17 debian Wow.desktop[5230]: 004e:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {bcde0395-e52f-467c-8e3d-c4579291692e} not registered
Oct  9 12:37:17 debian Wow.desktop[5230]: 004e:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {bcde0395-e52f-467c-8e3d-c4579291692e} could be created for context 0x1
Oct  9 12:37:17 debian Wow.desktop[5253]: 0061:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {bcde0395-e52f-467c-8e3d-c4579291692e} not registered
Oct  9 12:37:17 debian Wow.desktop[5253]: 0061:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {bcde0395-e52f-467c-8e3d-c4579291692e} could be created for context 0x1
Oct  9 12:37:17 debian Wow.desktop[5253]: 0061:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {bcde0395-e52f-467c-8e3d-c4579291692e} not registered
Oct  9 12:37:17 debian Wow.desktop[5253]: 0061:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {bcde0395-e52f-467c-8e3d-c4579291692e} could be created for context 0x1
I am using Debian 11 Bullseye and Wine: wine-5.0.3 (Debian 5.0.3-3).
```

Not really sure what to do, I have tried to redirect it to > /dev/null but doesn't work. It actually filled my whole disk space in few days (almost 200GB...). I that is the only error I see, it does the same if I open it via terminal. My launcher:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=World of Warcraft
Exec=wine "/home/basajaun/Games/World of Warcraft - WoTLK/Wow.exe"
Icon=/home/basajaun/Pictures/DesktopIcons/WoW_icon.svg
Type=Application
Categories=Wine;
```

By the way, the game itself works fine - the problem is the crazy spam that fils my disk.
Any ideas? Thank you!

EDIT:

Found a solution thanks to this: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=35748

But, I am having a problem with the launcher, when I add here the WINEDEBUG=-all, the launcher stops working:

```
Name=World of Warcraft
Exec=WINEDEBUG=-all wine "/home/basajaun/Games/World of Warcraft - WoTLK/Wow.exe"
Icon=/home/basajaun/Pictures/DesktopIcons/WoW_icon.svg
Type=Application
Categories=Wine;
```

Any idea how to make the launcher work with the WINEDEBUG=-all?

Thanks!

Comment: Found a solution thanks to this: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=35748

But, I am having a problem with the launcher, when I add here the WINEDEBUG=-all, the launcher stops working:
CODE: SELECT ALL

`code`Name=World of Warcraft
Exec=WINEDEBUG=-all wine "/home/basajaun/Games/World of Warcraft - WoTLK/Wow.exe"
Icon=/home/basajaun/Pictures/DesktopIcons/WoW_icon.svg
Type=Application
Categories=Wine; `code`
Any idea how to make the launcher work with the WINEDEBUG=-all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`WINEDEBUG` is an environment variable that needs to be set, but you can't use the shell syntax to set it from within your launcher config file. Instead, you can use the `env` command to set it like so:

```
Exec=env WINEDEBUG=-all wine "/home/basajaun/Games/World of Warcraft - WoTLK/Wow.exe"
```